# Website hanging in IE on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, windows-xp

I've got an ecommerce site ready to go live but am experiencing issues on IE 7/8 on Windows XP

The site loads up fine in IE on Windows 7 but on XP every page load I get the "Done" text in the statusbar and the browser just freezes for 7 - 10 seconds

I've gone through my javascript and made sure all DOM manipulation is done in a document ready function and I've put the site through the W3C validator and it's only moaning about a couple unencoded ampersands in URLs

Has anybody experienced this before? And did you manage to get it resolved?

Comment: Did you try to use DebugBar, insert alert statements to see where your code stucks ?
Have you enabled Javascript?

Comment: I'm not using debugbar, I'm using the built in IE console. I put a console.log('hello') on window.onload which fires and it freezes after that

Comment: and yes, of course Javascript is enabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after spending a stupid amount of time debugging I figured out fancybox 1.3.4 is responsible for the crash/hang! In particular is this block of CSS:

```
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-ne { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_ne.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-e { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_e.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-se { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_se.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-s { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_s.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-sw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_sw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-w { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_w.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-nw { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_nw.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

When this CSS block is commented out the page loads with no crashing.

No idea why that was causing it to happen but hey I'm just happy it's fixed!